# Error message "Mpeg-4 AAC decoder not installed" when playing video on Ubuntu 18.04.3 in VirtualBox

Tags: ffmpeg

I am unable to play videos on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 system running in VirtualBox due to the error message `Mpeg-4 AAC decoder not installed`.

The file requires MPEG-4 AAC decoder and H.264 (Main Profile) decoder, which are not installed. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run those commands ([source](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-enable-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-to-play-videos-files/)):

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvd-pkg gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg 
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```